# Adds needs relations to GitLab CI yaml but got an error: the job was not added to the pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to add needs between jobs in the Gitlab CI yaml configuration file.

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - package
  - deploy

maven-build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - branches
  ...
test:
  stage: test
  needs: [ "maven-build" ]
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
  ...
docker-build:
  stage: package
  needs: [ "test" ]
  only:
    - master
  ...
deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [ "docker-build" ]
  only:
    - master
  ...
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [ "docker-build" ]
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
  ...
```

I have used the GitLab CI online lint tools to check my syntax, **it is correct**.

But when I pushed the codes, it always complains:

```sh
    'test' job needs 'maven-build' job
    but it was not added to the pipeline

You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint
```

The GitLab CI did not run at all.

**Update**: Finally I made it. I think the `needs` position is sensitive, move all `needs` under the `stage`, it works. My original scripts included some other configuration between them.

Comment: Do you have any `rules` or `only`/`except`on your build job which prevents it from being created in certain cases?

Comment: which gitlab version are you on?

Comment: @kgorskowski I am using GitLab.com

Comment: @danielnelz Not used rules,but used `only` in the jobs. The original post is updated.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, and my yml passes the CI Lint

Comment: I create a simple test just echo as script with needs dependency. It works fine. Can you try comments complex script and test out.

Answer (score 43):

CI-jobs that depend on each other need to have the same limitations!

In your case that would mean to share the same `only` targets:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

maven-build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - branches

test:
  stage: test
  needs: [ "maven-build" ]
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - branches
```

that should work from my experience^^

Comment: I already made it work. I think the `needs` position is sensitive, move all `needs` under the `stage`, it works. My original scripts included some other configuration between them.

Comment: Well in my case it was exactly this. Jobs need to share same limitations. Thanks!

Comment: > In GitLab 13.9 and older, if needs: refers to a job that might not be added to a pipeline because of only, except, or rules, the pipeline might fail to create. 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#requirements-and-limitations

stupid me, i thought this was fixed.

Comment: Re-ordering the keyword 'needs' helped. Thank you.

Comment: checking for rules/only is a good point. Gitlab-CI Pipeline Editor showed to me, that the pipeline is valid even though the rules didn't match

Comment: Ordering "needs" after "stage" does not solve the problem. However, having the same conditions (rules, only, except, ...) does solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

> Finally I made it. I think the needs position is sensitive, move all needs under the stage, it works

Actually... that might no longer be the case with [GitLab 14.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/08/22/gitlab-14-2-released/#stageless-pipelines) (August 2021):

> ### Stageless pipelines
>
> Using the [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) keyword in your pipeline configuration helps to reduce cycle times by ignoring stage ordering and running jobs without waiting for others to complete.
>
> **Previously, `needs` could only be used between jobs on different stages.**
>
> **In this release, we’ve removed this limitation so you can define a `needs` relationship between any job you want**.
>
> As a result, you can now create a complete CI/CD pipeline without using stages by including `needs` in every job to implicitly configure the execution order.
> This lets you define a less verbose pipeline that takes less time to create and can run even faster.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_2/need.png -- Stageless pipelines]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30632).

Comment: Hi @VonC, Just a question not related to this thread. Is it possible to use a stage name instead of the job name to make a job dependent on another job? That is, instead of using "build-job" can I by any chance use "build" to make a job depend on job(s) with stage "build"? It doesn't work in dependencies but is there anything else with which it might work? Thanks.

Comment: @VibhavChaddha Not sure, I have not tested that use case. Let me know if you ask that as a separate question, for me to follow along.

Comment: Hi, @VonC I have posted a new question regarding my concern.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278440/can-we-use-a-stage-name-instead-of-a-job-name-to-make-a-job-dependent-on-another

Answer (score 0):

The rule in both jobs should be that same or otherwise GitLab cannot create job dependency between the jobs when the trigger rule is different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if the jobs are in different stages (as in my case), you have to define the jobs that will be done later with "." at the start.

Another interesting thing is GitLab's own CI/CD Lint online text editor does not complain there is an error. So you have to start the pipeline to see the error.

Below, notice the "." in ".success_notification" and ".failure_notification"

```
stages:
- prepare
- build_and_test
- deploy
- notification

#SOME CODE

build-StandaloneWindows64:
  <<: *build
  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-windows-mono-$IMAGE_VERSION
  variables:
    BUILD_TARGET: StandaloneWindows64

.success_notification:
  needs:
    - job: "build-StandaloneWindows64"
      artifacts: true
  stage: notification
  script:
    - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DiscordHooks/gitlab-ci-discord-webhook/master/send.sh
    - chmod +x send.sh
    - ./send.sh success $WEBHOOK_URL
  when: on_success

.failure_notification:
  needs:
    - job: "build-StandaloneWindows64"
      artifacts: true
  stage: notification
  script:
    - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DiscordHooks/gitlab-ci-discord-webhook/master/send.sh
    - chmod +x send.sh
    - ./send.sh failure $WEBHOOK_URL
  when: on_failure

#SOME CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turned out that the previous stage did not work out because of the only block, so the stage depending on it could not work out either.